# Using ampersand in c

Tags: c

In an attempt to solve a problem I faced whilst creating a program which can encrypt and decrypt a string (the input) of characters, I have decided to create another array called "char passb[81]"

The purpose of this new array is to store the corresponding uppercase characters of the input.  These characters will be used in other parts of my program.  I have included the code below.

```
int plength;
 char pass[81];

 printf("Please enter passphrase: \n");
 scanf("%s", &pass);
 plength=("%d", strlen(pass));

 {
 char passb[81];
 int p;
 for (p=0; p<plength; p++)
 {
     if(pass[p] >= 97 && pass[p] <= 122)
             {
             return((pass[p]-32), &passb);
             }
     else if (pass[p] >= 65 && pass[p] <= 90)
             {
             return((pass[p]), &passb);
             }
 }
 printf("\n");
 }
```

When I attempt to compile my program, I get the following error message:

```
test2.c: In function ‘main’:
test2.c:50:6: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast
  return((pass[p]-32), &passb);
  ^
test2.c:50:6: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-    local-addr]
test2.c:54:6: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast
  return((pass[p]), &passb);
  ^
test2.c:54:6: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
```

What can I do to address this problem?  Any contributions and response will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `return` as a function?

Comment: It looks like you try to return 2 values (`return((pass[p]-32), &passb);`) which makes no sense in C.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do with `return((pass[p]-32), &passb);`... Is return a function you've defined? If not, then that line doesn't do whatever it is you think it does.

Comment: @R_Kapp: How can you define a function with the same name as a keyword? Apparently OP uses an ancient C dialect (some decades ago, many C programs used function-syntax for `return`). Of course the parenthesis have no actual meaning for the compiler.

Comment: @Olaf: I don't think you can, but it might be want the OP was trying to attempt, which is what I was asking.

Comment: @R_Kapp Read my updated comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a return statement there, just an assignment:

```
if(pass[p] >= 97 && pass[p] <= 122)
{
    passb[p] = pass[p]-32;
}
else //don't need this either if (pass[p] >= 65 && pass[p] <= 90)
{
   passb[p] = pass[p];
}
```

All of which could be replaced with:

```
passb[p] = toupper(pass[p]);
```